# Oracle Bind array of sdo_geometry in C# with oracle Data access

Tags: c#, arrays, oracle, binding, nested

I have many sdo_gemetry c# object, Built in UDT in C# and i want to insert them into a a table (**SHAPE_SDO**) that have 2 columns **cms** as **varchar** and **POLY** as **SDO_GEOMETRY**. it takes a **long time** to insert them in a for loop. I decide to bind them in an array but i get this error :

> ORA-29875: failed in the execution of the ODCIINDEXINSERT routine
>   ORA-13354: incorrect offset in ELEM_INFO_ARRAY ORA-06512: at
>   "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 720 ORA-06512: at
>   "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 225 ORA-06512: at "GIS.FUNCTION1",
>   line 7

and this error repeats as much as the number of my array;

and this is my code:

```
    cmd = new OracleCommand()
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into SHAPE_SDO (CMS,POLY) values (:CMS,:POLY)";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.ArrayBindCount = allRecord.Count;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(":CMS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, CMS.ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);

    OracleParameter oracle_SDO_Param = new OracleParameter();
            oracle_SDO_Param.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object;
            oracle_SDO_Param.UdtTypeName = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY";
            oracle_SDO_Param.ParameterName = "POLY";
            oracle_SDO_Param.Value = POLY.ToArray();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(oracle_SDO_Param);
```